# ２つのintの入力の最大公約数を返す関数を作成したところ、きちんと機能していない(WA)原因が分からない

Tags: python, python3

最大公約数を返す関数を下記のように書いたのですが、テストデータに通したところ
"Wrong Answer" となってしまいます。
書き方に欠陥があると考えていますがどこが悪いのか見当たりません。
どなたか教えていただけると幸いです。

制約は 1 ≤ x, y ≤ 10^9 で、具体的にどのケースで誤判定したかは競技プログラミングの判定サイトを用いたため不明です。

**現状のソースコード:**

```
def GCD(x, y):
    if x > y:
        x, y = y, x
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        rem = y % x
        if rem == 0:
            return x
        else:
            return GCD(rem, x)

x,y = map(int,input().split())
GCD(x, y)
```

Comment: エラーになる具体的な引数は掲載できますか？
エラーが再現するデータがあれば回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: AOJというプログラミング競技サイトでWAとなったものなので、具体的にどのデータで引っかかっているのか不明です。申し訳ありません。

Comment: `python` の整数除算は負数において `C` や `C++` とは異なる挙動を示します。提示コードは負数を与えると無限再帰しちゃうのですが、その辺かも（全然違うかも）

Comment: 申し訳ありません。制約は1 ≤ x, y ≤ 10^9だそうです。

Comment: それと関数だけではなく、きちんと標準入力を受け取るようにしました(__main__などは力不足で使えないので簡素なものですが)。これでも根本的な原因は解決していないようでWAになってしまいます。

Comment: 入力と出力の制約はありませんか？また時間の制約はありませんか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

もしそのコードをそのまま提出してるのでしたら、単純に最大公約数を出力し忘れてるだけです

Comment: てっきり関数を通してreturnで返すだけで出力されているものだと勘違いしていました。。。。。きちんとprintしたところ通りました、お騒がせしました！

Answer (score 1):

一応思いついたのが、引数に０を与えたときに０割が発生している、とかでしょうか。

Comment: 確かにご指摘の通りだと思います。ですが直してみてもWAである事には変わりませんでした。(質問のコードに組み込ませて頂きました、ありがとうございます。)